# NSDecimal requires a bridge cast

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, casting

I'm setting a handful of global parameters that I will eventually insert into my sqlite db.  One of the text fields should only have decimals put into it but I am having an issue when trying to set the NSDecimal variable to the text fields value.

```
global_Raw_Value = self.Value.text;//self.Valueis the text field
```

totally new to iOS dev so any help converting the text fields value(self.Value) into an NSDecimal so I can insert the values into a sqlite table would be much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating NSDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035421/creating-nsdecimal)

Comment: The above question has your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is not providing an easy way putting values into an NSDecimal, so you have to do this yourself. This thread will help you: [Is there a way to create an NSDecimal without using NSNumber and creating autoreleased objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035421/creating-nsdecimal)

On the other hand you can just use a NSNumber or a regular float:

```
NSString *inputString = self.Value.text;
float inputFloat = [inputString floatValue];
NSNumber *mynumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputFloat]
```