# NSDecimalNumber compare fails

Tags: objective-c, ios

Why is `result` `NSOrderedDescending`?

```
NSDecimalNumber *decimal = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"2.6"];

NSComparisonResult result = [decimal compare:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.6]];
```

Comment: I bet it's an internal rounding issue. Did you try @"2.60" and 2.6 ?

Comment: Thanks Mark. Thought I was being smart using NSDecimalNumber but this rounding err thing runs deeper. Ended up using NSDecimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`2.6` cannot be represented exactly as a floating-point number, but `NSDecimal` can represent this value exactly (that's why we need NSDecimals in the first place).

According to [IEEE 754 Calculator](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), `2.6` gets converted to `2.5999999046325684`, which is less than `2.6`, and therefore compares as `NSOrderedDescending`.

Comment: Using NSDecimal works. I also used handy CPDecimalFromString from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035421/creating-nsdecimal