# NSDecimalNumber to the power of NSDecimalNumber

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, math, nsdecimalnumber

I have two NSDecimalNumbers and I need to apply one to the power of the other, originally this code was using doubles and I could compute this with the pow() function like this:

```
double result = pow(value1, value2);
```

The problem I have is I am converting the code to use NSDecimalNumbers and although they include the method toThePowerOf, it only accepts int values. At the moment the only solution I have to this problem is to convert the NSDecimalNumbers Temporarily but this results in a loss of precision.

```
double value1 = [decimal1 doubleValue];
double value2 = [decimal2 doubleValue];

double result = pow(value1, value2);
NSDecimalNumber *decimalResult = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:result];
```

Is there a way I can do this computation with NSDecimalNumbers and not lose the precision?

I need this to work with non integer values for example:

```
value1 = 1.06
value2 = 0.0277777777
```

Comment: Is the range of `value2` limited in any way?

Answer (score 4):

As Joe points out, if you want to do this for positive integer powers, you can use `NSDecimalPower()` on an NSDecimal struct derived from your NSDecimalNumber (I personally prefer working with the structs, for [performance reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704504/what-is-the-right-choice-between-nsdecimal-nsdecimalnumber-cfnumber/1710277#1710277)).

For the more general case of working with negative integers and fractional values, I have some code that I've modified from Dave DeLong's DDMathParser library. He has since removed the NSDecimal portion of this library, but you can find [the last commit for this support](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/commit/6121b9d8c3651bcafeb8d89063471b1ba2aa9d3c). I extended Dave's exponential support into the following function:

```
extern NSDecimal DDDecimalPower(NSDecimal d, NSDecimal power) {
    NSDecimal r = DDDecimalOne();
    NSDecimal zero = DDDecimalZero();
    NSComparisonResult compareToZero = NSDecimalCompare(&zero, &power);
    if (compareToZero == NSOrderedSame) {
        return r;
    }
    if (DDDecimalIsInteger(power))
    {
        if (compareToZero == NSOrderedAscending)
        {
            // we can only use the NSDecimal function for positive integers
            NSUInteger p = DDUIntegerFromDecimal(power);
            NSDecimalPower(&r, &d, p, NSRoundBankers);
        }
        else
        {
            // For negative integers, we can take the inverse of the positive root
            NSUInteger p = DDUIntegerFromDecimal(power);
            p = -p;
            NSDecimalPower(&r, &d, p, NSRoundBankers);
            r = DDDecimalInverse(r);
        }
    } else {
        // Check whether this is the inverse of an integer        
        NSDecimal inversePower = DDDecimalInverse(power);
        NSDecimalRound(&inversePower, &inversePower, 34, NSRoundBankers); // Round to 34 digits to deal with cases like 1/3

        if (DDDecimalIsInteger(inversePower))
        {
            r = DDDecimalNthRoot(d, inversePower);
        }
        else
        {
            double base = DDDoubleFromDecimal(d);
            double p = DDDoubleFromDecimal(power);
            double result = pow(base, p);
            r = DDDecimalFromDouble(result);
        }        
    }
    return r;
}
```

This runs exact calculations on positive integer powers, negative integer powers, and fractional powers that map directly to roots. It still falls back on floating point calculations for fractional powers that don't cleanly fall into one of those bins, though.

Unfortunately, this requires a few of his other supporting functions to work. Therefore, I've uploaded my enhanced versions of his [_DDDecimalFunctions.h](http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/_DDDecimalFunctions.h) and [_DDDecimalFunctions.m](http://sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/_DDDecimalFunctions.m) that provide this functionality. They also include NSDecimal trigonometry, logarithm, and a few other functions. There are currently some issues with convergence on the tangent implementation, which is why I haven't finished a public post about this.

Comment: So this uses pow if it is fractional? The problem I have is I don't want to use pow and I know my numbers are going to be real numbers. Sorry I may have been unlcear about this in the question to start.

Comment: @RobGill - For even fractions (1/3, 1/4), it's able to simplify those into exact roots and maintain precision. The `pow()` is a fallback for cases that don't map to roots or inverses, like 2^(1.05). I'm not aware of any other NSDecimal / NSDecimalNumber implementations of exponentials that are more precise than this out there, which is why I built off of Dave's initial implementation of this. If you can find such functions, please let me know, because I could use it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem recently and developed my own function to do exactly this. The function has will calculate any base to any power as long as it yields a real answer if it determines a real answer cannot be calculated it returns `NSDecimalnumber.notANumber`

I have posted my solution as an answer to the same question that I posted so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174239/how-does-the-pow-function-work) is the link.