# pow returns different results using Double or Decimal with negative exponent

Tags: ios, swift

With Xcode 11.1 if I run a playground with:

```
pow(10 as Double, -2)  // 0.01
```

I get same output using Float:

```
pow(10 as Float, -2) // 0.01
```

But if I try to use the pow(Decimal, Int) as in:

```
pow(10 as Decimal, -2) // NaN
```

Does anybody know why?

Is there a better way to deal with positive and negative exponent with pow and Decimal? I need Decimal as they behave as I expect with currency value.

EDIT: I know how to resolve that from math perspective, I'd like to understand why it happens and/or if it can be solved without adding on the cyclomatic complexity of my code (e.g. checking if the exponent is negative and executing 1 / pow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this struct give us an idea about the problem:

```
public struct Decimal {

    public var _exponent: Int32

    public var _length: UInt32 // length == 0 && isNegative -> NaN

    public var _isNegative: UInt32

    public var _isCompact: UInt32

    public var _reserved: UInt32

    public var _mantissa: (UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16)

    public init()

    public init(_exponent: Int32, _length: UInt32, _isNegative: UInt32, _isCompact: UInt32, _reserved: UInt32, _mantissa: (UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16, UInt16))
}
```

The length condition should be satisfacted only length == 0, but as UInt32 doesn't represents fractionary numbers the condition is satisfacted...

Answer (score 6):

Well, algebraically, `x^(-p) == 1/(x^(p))`

So, convert your negative power to a positive power, and then take the reciprocal.

```
1/pow(10 as Decimal, 2) // 0.01
```

Comment: Thanks Ali, I edited the question to clarify my intent with it.

Answer (score 2):

That's simply how NSDecimal / NSDecimalNumber works: it doesn't do negative exponents. You can see a rather elaborate workaround described here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12095004/341994

As you can see, the workaround is *exactly* what you've already been told: look to see if the exponent would be negative and, if so, take the inverse of the positive root.

Answer (score 0):

...  if it can be solved without adding on the cyclomatic complexity of my code ...

```
extension Decimal {
    func pow(i: Int)->Decimal {
        i < 0 ? 1.0 / Foundation.pow(self, -i) : Foundation.pow(self, i)
    }
}
```

it is really not so complex to use it, from your example ....

```
(10 as Decimal).pow(i: -2) // 0.01
```

Comment: ternary operators increase cyclomatic complexity, you still have two branches to test

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find my point of view for this Apple function implementation, Note the following examples:

> ```
> pow(1 as Decimal, -2) // 1; (1 ^ Any number) = 1
> pow(10 as Decimal, -2) // NAN
> pow(0.1 as Decimal, -2) // 100
> pow(0.01 as Decimal, -2) // 10000
> pow(1.5 as Decimal, -2) // NAN
> pow(0.5 as Decimal, -2) // NAN
> ```

It seems like, pow with decimal don't consider any floating numbers except for 10 basis. So It deals with:

> 0.1 ^ -2 == (1/10) ^ -2 == 10 ^ 2 // It calculates it appropriately, It's 10 basis 10, 100, 1000, ...
>
> 1.5 ^ -2 == (3/2) ^ -2 // (3/2) is a floating number ,so deal with it as Double not decimal, It returns NAN.
>
> 0.5 ^ -2 == (1/2) ^ -2 // (2) isn't 10 basis, So It will be dealt as (1/2) as It is, It's a floating number also. It returns NAN.

Answer (score -1):

I think this could be a bug on Swift's compiler.

> EDIT: This is a weird behaviour on Objective-C's `NSDecimalNumber`, see @matt's comment on this answer below.

As stated by @jawadAli on his answer

> Well, algebraically, x^(-p) == 1/(x^(p))

This formula is correct therefore the following statements should be equal

```swift
let ten: Decimal = 10
let one: Decimal = 1
let answer: Decimal = 0.01

pow(ten, -2)       // NaN
one / pow(ten, 2)  // 0.01
one / (ten * ten)  // 0.01
answer             // 0.01
```

Trying this with other data types would result to `0.01`.

I also tried to replicate this by using other negative exponents on `Decimal` data type and it seems to always evaluate to `NaN`. With the exceptions of **1**, **0**, and **-1**

```swift
(1...100).forEach {
  print(pow(-2, -$0)) // NaN
  print(pow(-1, -$0)) // Correct
  print(pow(0, -$0))  // Correct
  print(pow(-1, -$0)) // Correct
  print(pow(-2, -$0)) // NaN
}
```

I would suggest that you use a different Data Type for now.

Comment: It's not a bug in Swift, because Objective-C behaves the same way.

Comment: @matt hmm weird, but why?

Comment: If you wanted to list the weird behaviors of NSDecimal / NSDecimalNumber, you could write a book. Google "NSDecimalNumber weird behavior". :) It's largely because of the very strange and elaborate NSDecimal struct that lies at the bottom of it.

Comment: I see, this is alarming.